# How to render and add similar item to the list of items from the api in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-context

[image: Component Diagram]

I have a component called ListItem which have 7 fields(components)ignore diagram it has only 4,all are react select component also it has save and delete icon for each ListItem. I am using context, where i have set lists=[] , On useEffect I have set the lists to array of objects that I got from api . I have a component Lists that renders this ListItem component by using map function. Now I want to add another list at the front of the first ListItem , I am able to do so and a record is made in the Database. I have implemented pagination and on pagination I am prepending all the list items that I have in state along with the items that's being returned from api since the product I add was inserted into Database so at the api call for the last page I also get the data that I added at the top, so I see same data twice. 1)When I clicked Add Product 2)As last ListItem since the record was added to database. What will be the correct approach to deal with such scenerio. Please ignore if I can't make sense because this is my first question.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give specific advice without seeing your code, but I think I understand the problem.  You need to keep the items that you are adding separate from the ones which you retrieved from the database.  You also need to keep any UI state separate from the data.

In terms of user experience, I think it's good to show the item which they just added at the top even if it doesn't actually belong on that page.  I would style it differently (probably a darker background color) to indicate that this is an added item rather than a true element of the list.

When they navigate to a different page of the list then the added item should not be prepended anymore.  They would only see the added item in its actual position in the list, which may or may not be on that page.

Here is some psuedo-code for how I would handle this.

```
const List = () => {
  
  // store the current page (or possibly store it in the context)
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  // some hook which accesses API data via context
  // should refresh the API fetch when the page changes
  const items = useListPage(page);

  // store items which were added while on this page
  const [addedItems, setAddedItems] = useState([]);

  // clear added items on page change
  useEffect(() => {
    setAddedItems([]);
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <div>
      <AddForm
        // AddForm component would handle the POST request
        // if successful, add that item to the List state via onSuccess callback
        onSuccess={(object) => setAddedItems([object, ...addedItems])}
      />
      {addedItems.map((item) => (
        <ListItem
          {...item}
          key={item.id}
          temporary={true} // some sort of flag to control styling
        />
      ))}
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ListItem
          {...item} 
          key={item.id} 
          temporary={false}
        />
      ))}
      <Pagination 
        page={page}
        setPage={page}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I also have another requirement that I need to add item on clicking of a button that appears when I hover over the edge of each item just like in JIRA software we can create issue in backlog page using hover (exactly same).

Comment: I was assuming that the dummy component AddForm (which I haven’t implemented) would handle that.  That component would have state properties like isClicked, fields, isPosting, etc.  You would first render a button.  Clicking (or hovering) the button would set isClicked to true and based on that you would hide the button and show a form where you enter the properties for your new item.  You would submit the form and get a response from the server, then at that point you call back to the parent List component through the onSuccess prop which we provided to the AddForm component.

Comment: Separation of concerns is always good.  The only communication that needs to happen between the section where you add an item and the section where you view a list of items is that the list needs to know the item that was added so that it can be displayed.